# Find objects in SQL database that match a value in a certain column

Tags: android, sql

I have a database like this:

```
id | level | text
1  | 1     | blah
2  | 1     | blah2
3  | 1     | blah3
4  | 2     | hi
5  | 2     | hello
```

I have a method where I want to return a list of the objects that are in level 1

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, ????, null, orderBY);

if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            Text t = new Text();
            t.setId(String.valueOf(cursor.getString(0)));
            t.setLevel(String.valueOf(cursor.getString(1)));
            t.setText(cursor.getString(2));
            list.add(t);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return list;
```

What do I put in the query parameters to isolate only the objects that are in level 1??

Answer (score 4):

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, "level = 1", null, null, null, orderBY);
```

You need to filter it using the `WHERE` condition!